# Rendering to texture hides the front face,something's wrong with the z buffer?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I want to render my scene to a texture and apply a blur shader to this texture .The problem is that when I draw back my texture the front faces of the cubes are invisible

without supersampling

[image]

with supersampling

[image]

*Ignore the opaque thing around the cube in both photos.I double render the cube once with less alpha and more scale ,I disabled this but I have the same problem.

For some reason I am using the y as z and z as y,so the front face of the cube has less y than the back face(instead of z)  ,I am guessing something is wrong with the z-buffer.

The render to texture code:

```
public class RenderOnTexture {
    private float m_fboScaler = 1f;
    private boolean m_fboEnabled = true;
    private FrameBuffer m_fbo = null;
    private TextureRegion m_fboRegion = null;
    public RenderOnTexture(float scale) {
        int width = (int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*scale);
        int height = (int) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*scale);
        m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(width * m_fboScaler), (int)(height * m_fboScaler), false);
        m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
        m_fboRegion.flip(false,false);
    }
    public void begin(){
        if(m_fboEnabled)
        {                  
            m_fbo.begin();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0,0,0);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
    }
    public TextureRegion end(){
        if(m_fbo != null)
        {
            m_fbo.end();
            return m_fboRegion;
        }  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this works with libgdx, but it looks like you don't have a depth attachment in your FBO.

Comment: You probably didn't attach a depth buffer to your FBO, but even if you did... you're only clearing the color buffer. So you need to address both of those issues.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman and RetoKoradi ,Ok I searched and it seems that you cant have a depth attachment with  FrameBuffer of libgdx ,I am translating some old code of me from c++ to render to texture from the ground up .I will post back when I finish.

Comment: You can--it's the Boolean argument in the FrameBuffer constructor. And make sure you are clearing the depth buffer in your begin method.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , srly? and I am here trying to port 100 lines of c++ opengl code. Thanks ,changing the boolean fixed the problem ,you can post the comment as an answer if you want.

Comment: I just happened to browse on my phone a minute ago. Glad it saved you from doing that!

Comment: It's insane that you'd think any sort of OpenGL wouldn't have a depth buffer, that's how *any* 3D rendering works with the commonly accepted model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boolean argument in the FrameBuffer enables a depth buffer attachment. And the depth buffer must be cleared along with the color buffer.